# Identificar un espacio en un string y sacar su index (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, condiciones, function

Estoy realizando un proyecto y no logro dar con este ejercicio, se los comparto.
Empieza fácil:

**- Puedes contar cuantas letras tiene tu nombre?**

```
let nombre = 'Pepito';
const charsCounter = a => {
    return 'El string tiene ' + a.length + ' letras';
}
console.log(charsCounter(nombre));
```

Y aquí es donde no comprendo qué hacer:

**- Añade tu apellido a "name" e indica en que posición del string empieza (modificando la función prueba a buscar el espacio entre el nombre y el apellido).**

Se me ocurrió hacer un bucle for con un condicional if que, al detectar un espacio vacío en el string "Pepito asdasd", guarde ese índice y haga un return para salir de la función, pero mi pregunta es:

¿¿Cómo puedo identficar un espacio vacío en un string y sacar el índice del mismo??

Y de paso, ¿¿está bien mi lógica o hay una forma más eficiente de hacerlo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar el método lastIndexOf():

```
let nombre = "Rodrigo";

const getLength = (nombre, apellido) => { 
   let completeName = `${nombre} ${apellido}`; // concateno con un espacio en el medio
   return [
    completeName.length,
    completeName.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1 // si quiero el indice de la ultima ocurrencia del caracter pasado por parametros lo hago con index.of()
    // si quiero devolver el indice del espacio solo quito el +1
   ]
};

let datos = getLength(nombre, "Garcia"); // llamo a la funcion y guardo el array de resultados
console.log(`Longitud del nombre completo ${datos[0]}`)
console.log(`Indice de la primera letra del apellido ${datos[1]}`)
```

Lo que no entendí es si queres devolver el tamaño del nombre completo o solo del nombre.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No sabía lo de lastIndexOf, me encanta aprender métodos, aunque siento que me olvido la mitad de los que aprendo 